# Why was my question on IIT closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/11236/is-there-a-phi-database) is on hold. I don't understand why. Rather than have a long comment thread, I'd rather discuss it here.

It seems like there are two objections:

1. The question is unclear. I don't understand how this could be. For any organism, we can calculate a value phi. I want to know what that value is. What's unclear?
2. It's not "on topic". Here are [those criteria](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

This is an actual problem I face. It's probably one of the shortest questions on this site, so I doubt it's "chatty".

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Question can be answered with one URL.

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Don't care to discuss it. (In fact, I'm pretty annoyed I have to write even this.)

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be as on-topic as the following analogous question:

Let ψ be a function from entities (e.g. humans, laptops) to {0,1}. ψ assigns to 1 those and only those entities that are able to feel pain; the rest get mapped to 0. A less confusing way of putting that would be to say that ψ(x) is the predicate "x is able to feel pain". Let a decision procedure for ψ be given, i.e., assume that scientists have a way of determining whether a given entity is able to feel pain or not, to some desired level of accuracy. The question is (v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub> : boolean):

> Is there  a listing of ψ for various entities somewhere? (e.g. ψ(human) = v<sub>1</sub>, ψ(laptop) = v<sub>2</sub>).

*Your question is on-topic iff this question is on-topic.*<sup>†</sup>

<sub>† You might object that the word 'consciousness' doesn't appear in this question, but the word '[pain](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pain/)' does.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure your point? But I would agree that your question also meets the criteria listed above, just like mine does. So I will not vote to close that question if you post it?

Comment: Don't think this *is* analogous. You're saying the question goes along the lines of "X="how conscious" lets scientifically estimate X with another function Y, is there a table of **X**?", but, Xodarap's question is "X="how conscious", a number of people consider the estimate Y to reflect X, is there a table of **Y**?"